# React Native with offline maps

Tags: png, mobile, react, offline, pbf

I am developing a React Native app functionality that will allow user to navigate with offline map.

I had luck with **react-native-maps** package and raster .jpg tiles. The main downside is that tiles for just one region with good zoom level take up 3 GB of space already and customer could need even more.

So I am trying to find a good offline solution to render vector tiles - **maplibre-react-native** looked promising but it only worked with a tileserver for me.

My target is creating a folder with standart {z}/{x}/{y} structure in the local storage of the device and accessing .pbf files as plain .pngs

Is that possible? Do I mandatory require a tileserver for decrypting .pbf format?